# Separar una columna en varias filas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, tengo un problema y espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy trabajando en SQL Server 2008 
 
Tengo una tabla en el cual deseo dividir el campo Numero_Guias en varias filas

```
OP        Numero_Guias
1         001015,001016,001017
2         001016
3         001017
4         001015,001017
...       ...
```

Por ejemplo que me quede de la siguiente forma

```
OP        Numero_Guia
1         001015
1         001016
1         001017
2         001016
3         001017
4         001015
4         001017
...       ...
```

Agradecido en antemano por sus respuestas

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Mi consulta es un extracto de una consulta que involucra 5 tablas, mi idea era separar cada fila de la tabla que contiene una cadena separado por comas y llenarlo en un xml, pero nose como insertar los datos en el xml para cada fila

Comment: En el buscador que tienes arriba prueba buscar  `[sql-server] split` ya hay varias respuestas al respecto.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, revisaré; es nuevo para mi el término split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table ejemplo_sql(
 op int null,
 Numero_Guia varchar(500) null 
);


insert into ejemplo_sql (op, Numero_Guia) values
(1, '001015,001016,001017'),
(2, '001016'),
(3, '001017'),
(4, '001015,001017');


select
    p.op as op,
    ltrim(tabla_spliteada.value) as numero_guia
from ejemplo_sql p
outer apply string_split(p.Numero_Guia, ',') as tabla_spliteada;
```

A partir de la tabla, podes hacer uso de OUTER APPLY para relacionar el resultado de string_split por cada elemento que tengas en la tabla [ejemplo_sql]. El ltrim va por si quedase algun espacio en blanco luego de hacer el split.

Comment: Hola Ignacio, al momento que haces el insert entiendo que la tabla ejemplo_sql puede ser una tabla auxiliar. ¿Hay  forma de llenar dicha tabla mediante un bucle?, lo que sucede tengo más de 1000 filas

Comment: Hola @Joshin, quizas no necesites llenarla mediante un bucle (espero sino te depara un cursor). 

Podrias probar con un CREATE TABLE [nombre de la tabla auxiliar] AS [select de la tabla].

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios Ignacio